# Is there a way to convert a class rma to class lm in R?

Tags: r, metafor

I have used the `rma.mv()` function from the 'metafor' package. Now I would like to plot the interaction effects.

I have tried various solutions and the one that seems closest is the `plot_model` function from package 'sjPlot'. This will work when I do a lm but not with my actual rma.mv. My first question is does this even matter, if it is just the interaction I am concerned about? If so, my follow up question is can class rma (or rma.mv) be converted to a lm so I can plot the interaction?

I first asked about plotting the class rma directly with sample data at the link below, but it went un answered.

[Is there a simple solution for plotting the interaction effect from a class RMA or RMA.MV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76603543/is-there-a-simple-solution-for-plotting-the-interaction-effect-from-a-class-rma)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/plots

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you! This is a great resource, but unfortunately does not specify how to plot the interaction effects. Thanks anyway though!